# Excel Macro: find column cell without activate it

Tags: excel, vba

i build a function to find column:

```
Function findColumn(NameSheet As String, ColName As String)
findColumn = 0
Worksheets(NameSheet).Select
Sheets(NameSheet).Range("A1").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    searchTerm = ActiveCell.Value
    If (LCase(ActiveCell.Value) = LCase(ColName)) Then
           findColumn = Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, 1)
           Exit Do
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
Loop 
End Function
```

This function works ! but it activate other worksheet, and i have to return to the previous sheet. The result is not seamless as there's a glitch of sheet transation while the function search the column address.

Is there any better way to do this ? because i'm using this method several time, and my partner does not satisfied when there's a glitch on every click on the cell.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible method, importantly it does not change the focus of your workbook at all. This will return the column number of the search term assuming it is in the first row, and return 0 if it is not found. If the `NameSheet` is invalid, a pop-up will inform you and it will return 0.

```
Function findColumn(NameSheet As String, ColName As String) As Long
    'Add Error checking to see if sheet Exists
    On Error Resume Next
        Dim sheetTest As String
        'Copy sheet name, just to see if the sheet is valid
         sheetTest = Sheets(NameSheet).Name
    'Check if sheet was found.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Sheet does not exist"
        Exit Function
    End If
        'Search the first column in the NameSheet for the ColName, and return 
        'the column number.
        findColumn = Sheets(NameSheet).Rows(1).Find(What:=ColName, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
End Function
```

Comment: + 1 on extra error handling + not using `Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, 1)` to get the column number :) You also might want to add `Thisworkbook` before every `Sheets(NameSheet)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout -> `Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, 1)` does not return the column number, but rather the column letter. If the OP wants `A` instead of `1`, this findColumn function will not work. I guess we could all assume different things the way the OP wrote the code... i.e - depending upon if we think `findColum = 0` is more indicative of what the OP is after, vs the `Mid` formula.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, True. I went to update it and then changed my mind. Most likely you'd want it to work on ThisWorkbook, but as written if put in a module it can be called from a different workbook inwhich case it will function on the current work book. We could always expand it to specify the desired workbook as well, but that might be over doing it?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Don't be mean. Siddharth Rout was telling me it was good that I _didn't_ use `Mid(ActiveCell.Address,2,1)`

Comment: Daniel, that was construed as being mean? In no way was I trying to be mean. I was simply making a point. Then I realized how we all may have interpreted the OP a bit differently. You taught him how to find the column number, which is great. If that is his real intent, even better. I left his return value as the column letter, which I thought was his intent. All of it is good. :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: My interpretation comes from OP assigning `0` to the function `findColumn = 0` So that means he/she is extracting the column number and not the column name. Even if you are extracting the column letter that method is still incorrect :) If the address is `$XFD$1` Then `Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, 1)` will give you incorrect results.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: Perhaps this might give you an exact reuslt if you are trying to extract the Column Name `in the above scenario` See this `Debug.Print Split(myRng.Address, "$")(1)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout -> good point. I stand corrected for lack of thoughtfulness :) Updating my answer, too!

Comment: Hi all (Daniel, SiddharthRout, and ScottHoltzman) you guys are fantastic, yeah i'm still new in this "Macro Thing", but you guys helps more than i expected.. big thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function that will work as you suggest, i believe, as it never `.Selects` or `.Activates` the sheet you are searching, while bringing back the column letter(s) you want. It also doesn't loop every cell, which can be very inefficient.

This function will return the column letter, not the number. If you want the number, see Daniel's code above.

```
Function findColumn(NameSheet As String, ColName As String)

With Worksheets(NameSheet)

    Dim myRng As Range
    Set myRng = .Rows(1).Find(ColName, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not myRng Is Nothing Then

        findColumn = Split(myRng.Address, "$")(1)

    Else

        findColumn = "Column Not Found"

    End If

End With


End Function
```